# iterator class using generator function

Tags: python, python-3.x

It is sometimes necessary for a generator function to expose state. In those situations it is advised to wrap the generator function as method `__iter__` in a class. Here is an example:

```
class C:
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(4):
            yield i            
            self.state = i
```

It is convenient to use this in a for loop since the for loop will call iter() on the object, however, the object itself is not an iterator, so you cannot do this:

```
c = C()
print(next(c))
```

Which is inconvenient. To get around this inconvenience I have come up with the following class:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.next = self.__iter__().__next__
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(4):
            yield i            
            self.state = i
    def __next__(self):
        return self.next()
```

Usage example:

```
c = C()
while 1:
    try:
        num = next(c)
        print(num)
        if num == 2:
            print("state:", c.state)
    except Exception:
        break
```

Is this the best way to design the class? I haven't seen this technique used anywhere else so I'm wondering why everyone else isn't using it, since the C objects can be used both as iterators and as iterables.

Comment: _"It is sometimes necessary for a generator function to expose state"_ — I'd say that you should have a concrete use case to demonstrate that claim, and that the example you have posted is too sketchy or hypothetical to be on-topic for Code Review.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a lot of extra code for very little gain, considering you can simply call `iter()` on an iterable object to return an iterator:

```
>>> c = C()
>>> i = iter(c)
>>> next(i)
0
>>> next(i)
1
>>> next(i)
2
>>> c.state
1
```

Also, note your new `class C` can have more than one iterator, with only 1 "state".  The first iterator is created automatically by the constructor, for use with the `next(c)` call.  Additional iterators are created each time you start looping over `c`, since `iter(c)` gets called and returns a new generator!

```
>>> c = C()
>>> next(c)
0
>>> print(next(c), c.state)
1 0
>>> print(next(c), c.state)
2 1
>>> for x in c: print(x, c.state)       # Start a new iteration
...
0 1
1 0
2 1
3 2
>>> print(next(c), c.state)             # Continue original iteration
3 2
>>> next(c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in __next__
StopIteration
```